# How to print a part from a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

[image: my_example]

The part that I want to **REMOVE** from printing `print_f4.blade.php` :

```
@extends('_formulaires.f4')

<style>
...
</style>

<div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between;">
  <a class="bu-print" id="" href="/">Retour</a>
  <a class="bu-print" id="buPrintF4" href="#" onclick="window.print()">Imprimer le formulaire</a>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%;">
  <label for="client">Sélectionner l\'entreprise pour passer à choisir ses plans de formation en bas :</label>
  <select name="client" id="client" style="padding: .5rem;">
    @foreach ($client as $cl)
      <option value="{{$cl->nrc_entrp}}">{{$cl->raisoci}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

The page's script that I want to **PRINT** `f4.blade.php` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src={{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}></script>
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    ...
  </style>


<div class="paper" style="padding:.5rem; font-family:Calibri, 'Segoe UI', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; background-color: #fff;">
  ...THE CONTENT TO PRINT
</div>
```

Print page button (from the first part) :
Imprimer le formulaire

HOW DO I REMOVE THE FIRST PART AND PRINT THE BELOW PART ?

Comment: There is a media type called print in CSS you can try, which you can use to decide what to show/hide when printing.

Comment: I added an answer. Please try it :-)

Comment: Okey brother thank you I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your print_f4 in a div with class called "hide-from-print" and use the following CSS:

```
//CSS

@media print {
  .hide-from-print { 
      display: none !important; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!